# Storing a model instance as a service during the session

Tags: php, session, dependency-injection, phalcon

I want to access to profile of the current user across the application (read/write). The user profile is an in instance of `User` model. Is it possible to store it on session as a service? If not, what is best practice? 
Here is my login code. (ajax-based login)

```
    function loginAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();
    {
        $request = (array)$this->request->getJsonRawBody();
        $user = User::findFirstByUsername($request['username']);

        if (password_verify($request['password'], $user->password)) {
            $userModel = User::findFirst('username="'.$request['username'].'"');
            $this->getDI()['session']->set('auth', $user->id);
            $this->user = $user;
            jsonResponse($user);
        } else {
            http_response_code(401);
            jsonResponse(['message' => 'invalid']);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to achieve that. Let me share with you the one I've used in my own project...

First I've created a [Component](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_User_Component.html) to deal with authentication related stuff such as checking the current session status (guest, user, admin), storing the current user specs, authentication procedures, etc.

```
namespace MyApp\Components;

use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component as PhComponent;

class Authentication extends PhComponent
{
  // ...
}
```

Then, I've [registered this component in the main App's DI](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#registering-services-in-the-container) container:

```
$di->setShared('authentication', 'MyApp\Components\Authentication');
```

So I can use from my controllers, views, etc. Like:

```
function homeAction()
{
    //...
    if($this->authentication->isGuest()) {
    //...
}
```

Finally to store data using the session. Phalcon provide a [persistent session bag](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/session.html#persistent-data-in-components) that you can use to easily store a serialized version of the model in the current session:

```
class Authentication extends PhComponent
{
  // ...
  function authenticate($username, $password)
  {
        // ... Authentication logic
        if($validCredentials) {
              $this->persistent->currentUser = $userModel;
        }
        // ...
  }
}
```